# Difference between invalidateLayout() and reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit

I am wondering what some of the differences are between `invalidateLayout()` and `reloadData()`
I have read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617728-invalidatelayout) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata) but am left with the following questions:

1. I have data as an array such that `cellForItemAt indexPath` can reference the array directly with `dataArray[indexPath.item]` and each data object in the array can populate the cell. `reloadData()` will ensure that when a change is made to the `dataArray` this is reflected in the `collectionView`. With some minor testing it appears that `invalidateLayout()` will also observe this change. Is this always true?
2. Both functions appear to have the same effect with regards to resizing the cells, is this always true?
3. When `invalidateLayout()` is called, will `cellForItemAt indexPath` also be called for each cell as with `reloadData()`?
4. If all the above are true, then would you ever even need to use `reloadData()` since Apple says to use it sparingly?

Any other comments on the differences between the two functions on a fundamental level would be helpful (when to use each one, etc)

Comment: You should always use reloadData when you want to update a content of cells.
`invalidateLayout()` doesn't trigger cellForItem (at least it doesn't guarantee it), it rather updates the sizes and layout.
Updating layout (like rotating a device) - invalidateLayout, data - reloadData

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further testing...

1. `cellForItemAt indexPath` will be called only for cells which were not on screen but are now on screen as a result of the `invalidateLayout()`.
2. This appears to be true
3. See answer to question 1. This could cause an issue if you have moved cells around and the data in each cell is not in the same order as the data source.
4. I am now using `reloadData()` a lot less

In general, it looks like `reloadData()` also calls `invalidateLayout()` (or at least has a similar effect) and will trigger `cellForItemAt indexPath` for every cell. `invalidateLayout()`, however, will only call `cellForItemAt indexdPath` if the cell is now within the screen bounds and needs to be reloaded as a result of the layout change.

Comment: Thank you dear sir Why would apple even need to properly document those stuff when we an army of SO-ers spending multiple hours figuring basic stuff out.